# Drag and drop in reactjs not working

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop

I created react component:

```
class SecondSqIn extends React.Component{

render(){

allowDrop:(ev)=>{
ev.preventDefault();
}

drop: (ev)=>{
ev.preventDefault();
var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}

    return(
        <div
        id='sq3'
        onDrop={this.drop}
        onDragOver={this.allowDrop}
        >
        {console.log('return')}
        </div>  
    )
}
}
```

And second one:

```
class Apple extends React.Component{
render(){

drag: (ev)=>{
ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}
    return(
        <div
        id='apple'
        draggable="true"
        onDragStart = {this.drag}>
        </div>
    )
}
}
onDragStart: PropTypes.func.isRequired
export default Apple;
```

that is suppose to be dragged between two elements like the first one:

It is not working. It is working when I paste function code directly in the curly brackets-  onDragOver={this.allowDrop}. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You methods shouldn't be defined within render; they need to all be attached to the component itself.
I.e:

```
drag(ev){
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

render(){
```